# ubuntu 19.10 corrupts ntfs formatted sd card

Tags: dual-boot, sd-card, ntfs-3g

I have a micro SD card ntfs formatted and inserted in a dual boot machine (win 10 / ubuntu 19.10). While it works fine with win 10 (both read & write), every attempt to write to it in ubuntu leads to corruption! Reading from it files written by windows is OK. And, yes, fast boot is switched off in windows. Oh, yes, I have tried other cards too, and I get the same behavior.

Quite frustating. Any suggestion would be very much appreciated!

======================================

Some answers to questions stated in the comments: 1) It is a 2-in-1 Teclast F5 2) By "corrupting" I mean that if I copy, for example, a folder to the card, you see the folder, but it gets corrupted and you need Windows to repair the card! However, folders copied to it in Windows, remain OK in Linux too! 3) Yes, I own the mount point as a user. I have even experimented mounting it with fstab using uuid, but the same phenomenon occurs! 4) The card works without problem in Linux too, if I format it to exFAT! The problem occurs only if I format the card to NTFS

I hope these clarify the issue.

Comment: Please tell us about the computer: brand name and model. If possible, please tell us about the card reader too (brand name and model) if you can find it. -- By the way, you do unmount/eject the card before unplugging it?

Comment: Make sure you properly unmount the card each and every time again.

Comment: "every attempt to write to it in ubuntu leads to corruption" what is your definition of corruption? You claim "ubuntu 19.10 corrupts ntfs formatted sd card" but where is the proof? Because if this is true it warrants reporting it as a "critical bug". Not impossible to happen but are you sure about that claim?

Answer (score 0):

Common problem. You need to take ownership of the mount point.

First be sure the card is mounted.
Use the **lsblk** and **blkid** commands to find the name of the mount point. It's a string of characters.

Then issue this command:
sudo chown $USER:$USER /media/"user name"/"mount point name" -R
entering your user name and the name found in the first commands not including the " "..

You should be okay now.

Comment: How can this help with data corruption?